# how do I print the list for this

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Enter the Account no :");//in my main class
int accNo=sc.nextInt();
switch(n)
{
    case 1 ->{
            
                    
        Account ac=nbank.searchAccount(accNo);//account is my other class
        if(ac!=null)
        {
                    
        System.out.println("Enter the Amount to Deposite :");
        double amt=sc.nextDouble();
                        
        List<Trans> tr=nbank.deposite(accNo,amt);//Trans is also class and I created the list for this class and Trans contains the following below methods
                                            
System.out.println("AccNo :"+tr.getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+tr.getTransId()+"  type: "+tr.getType()+" Amount :"+tr.getWithAmt()+"  Status :"+tr.getStatus()+" Date :"+tr.getDate());
```

From the withdraw method, I'm getting a list, but somehow I can't print the list contents using LinkedList. For every method it shows method not found. Class I made are as Trans(getter and setter), bank as logic.

How do I print the list for the above programs using LinkedList?

```
List<Trans> withdraw(int accNo,double amt)//in my bank class where i'm implementing the logic and trying to store to other classes.
```

Here my intention is to view the withdraw the transaction done by the customer in my main():

```
{
    List<Trans> tr=new LinkedList<Trans>();
    Account ac=searchAccount(accNo);
    if(ac instanceof FDAccount)
        tr=((FDAccount)ac).withdraw(amt);
    else if(ac instanceof Account)
        tr=ac.withdraw(amt);
    return tr;
}
```

This is my withdraw method that is called by `List<Trans> tr=nbank.withdraw(accNo,amt);`

```
UserUI.java:189: error: cannot find symbol
                                                        System.out.println("AccNo :"+tr.getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+tr.getTransId()+"  type: "+tr.getType()+" Amount :"+tr.getDepAmt()+"  Status :"+tr.getStatus()+" Date :"+tr.getDate());
                                                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getAccNo()
  location: variable tr of type List<Trans>
UserUI.java:189: error: cannot find symbol`
```

Error like this etc.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: It's not clear what does `FDAccount.withdraw` or `Account/withdraw` do? Why do you even need a `LinkedList`? Please have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your Q and I can take another look

Comment: FDAccount is my another class also it contains overriden method List<Trans> withdraw(amt) from Account class. Actually its the practice purpose to convert the Bank program which I created using the array into the LinkedList

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) as returned by `withdraw` method. As such it does not have method `getAccNo`.

You probably mean reference to an instance of `Trans` in the list e.g. for the first Trans in the `List`:

```java
tr.get(0).getAccNo()
```

Or for every `Trans`:

```java
for (Trans tran : tr) {
  System.out.println("AccNo :"+tran.getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+tran.getTransId()+"  type: "+tran.getType()+" Amount :"+tran.getWithAmt()+"  Status :"+tran.getStatus()+" Date :"+tran.getDate());
}
```

Hard to be more specific or sure without additional clarifications/code in your question.

Comment: now can you help me to get to it

Comment: now is it understandable??

Comment: @AbrarMd not really. If you want to print each `Trans` then my answer will do that. As I already point out, `tr` is a `List` not a `Trans` so you need to access and call print for each `Trans`

Answer (score 1):

As @xlm said, tr is a List, you only can access getter by index. You can use `for loop` or `foreach`, you can't use `tr.getAcNo()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list, in java you must loop or iterate through the list, for an example:

```
//indexed loop
for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("AccNo :"+tr.get(i).getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+tr.get(i).getTransId()+"  type: "+tr.get(i).getType()+" Amount :"+tr.get(i).getWithAmt()+"  Status :"+tr.get(i).getStatus()+" Date :"+tr.get(i).getDate());
}
```

or

```
//foreach loop
for (Trans trans: tr) {
    System.out.println("AccNo :"+trans.getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+trans.getTransId()+"  type: "+trans.getType()+" Amount :"+trans.getWithAmt()+"  Status :"+trans.getStatus()+" Date :"+trans.getDate());
}
```

I think you want to search through the list and print a specific element, to do this, you need account number that want to search, here is some code for you:

```
for (Trans trans: tr) {
    if (accNo.equals(trans.getAccNo())) {
            System.out.println("AccNo :"+trans.getAccNo()+"  TransID :"+trans.getTransId()+"  type: "+trans.getType()+" Amount :"+trans.getWithAmt()+"  Status :"+trans.getStatus()+" Date :"+trans.getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: and suppose if i want to see the only one account what i can do to do so and That one may be in first position or last or somewhere in middle